# Invoke serverless-offline Lambda function by SNS message from Hosted AWS SNS using serverless-offline-sns

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, serverless-framework

`serverless-offline-sns` says [in its docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-offline-sns#hosted-aws-sns-configuration) that in order to listen to a hosted SNS on AWS you need the following:

```
custom:
  serverless-offline-sns:
    localPort: ${env:LOCAL_PORT}
    remotePort: ${env:SNS_SUBSCRIBE_REMOTE_PORT}
    host: 0.0.0.0
    sns-subscribe-endpoint: ${env:SNS_SUBSCRIBE_ENDPOINT}
    sns-endpoint: ${env:SNS_ENDPOINT}
```

But I don't know where to get the required environment values:

- `${env:SNS_SUBSCRIBE_REMOTE_PORT}`
- `${env:SNS_SUBSCRIBE_ENDPOINT}`
- `${env:SNS_ENDPOINT}`

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the source code I was able to get an SNS hosted in AWS to trigger my local function as the documentation wasn't very clear

Here is the configuration I used:

```
serverless-offline-sns:
    sns-endpoint: sns.${self:provider.region}.amazonaws.com
    sns-subscribe-endpoint: <ngrok_url>
    remotePort: 80
    localPort: <ngrok_port>
    accountId: ${self:provider.accountId}
```

Example usage:

1. Use ngrok: `ngrok http 4002`
2. Setup config like so:

```
serverless-offline-sns:
    sns-endpoint: sns.${self:provider.region}.amazonaws.com
    sns-subscribe-endpoint: xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io
    remotePort: 80
    localPort: 4002
    accountId: ${self:provider.accountId}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-offline-sns#installation, I learned that those values are optional. They are advanced settings for a more advanced configuration. Simply delete them from your config and you'll be good to go.

This will work just fine:

```
custom:
  serverless-offline-sns:
    port: 4002
    debug: false
```